# shellexecute() function to open a link file is not working, don't know,why?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

Code

```
int nRet = (int)ShellExecute( NULL, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Documents and Settings\\kse8.KSE\\Desktop\\lnk file\\1.lnk"),NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL );
```

always getting

> Error Code 2 in nRet

don't know why 
 "1.lnk" file which is a shortcut of a pdf is not getting open ?

you can create these scenario simply by these steps
1)create a shortcut of a pdf file i.e, (shift + f10) ,then "create shortcut"
2)rename it as 1.lnk
both pdf file and shortcut are placed in the same folder of desktop.
and then execute the command

```
int nRet = (int)ShellExecute( NULL, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Documents and Settings\\kse8.KSE\\Desktop\\lnk file\\1.lnk"),NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL )
```

Comment: You have spaces and unescaped backslashes in your string

Comment: now,comeon,it's a small copy-paste error,,,,                                                        int nRet = (int)ShellExecute( NULL, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Documents and Settings\\kse8.KSE\\Desktop\\lnk file\\1.lnk"),NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL );                                                                                              now happy.:)                                                                                                  can i expect now a change of this "-1" or now no one is active

Comment: error code 2 indicates file not found.

Comment: as 1.lnk refers to some file location you need to get path of it. then you can you shellexecute using that path.

Comment: i simply have a pdf file ,of which i have created a shortcut and renamed it as 1.lnk, both are in the same folder of desktop,when i am trying to execute the above code ,,pdf is not getting open,,,,just want to know why?

Comment: first try to give full path of pdf file not link file, is it opening or not? or you can try replacing _T("open") with NULL(it may work sometime).

Comment: int nRet = (int)ShellExecute( NULL, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Documents and Settings\\kse8.KSE\\Desktop\\lnk file\\Vol2ENG.pdf"),NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL );                                                                                                 successfully opened pdf                                                                                    and                                                                                                    even replacing_T("open") with NULL is not able to open through lnk  file

Comment: not working,still not able to open through lnk file

Comment: Probably the path is wrong, even if you got the backslashes right. That's why you get error 2 (path not found)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani :- i have written the steps,,file and shorcut (renamed as 1.lnk) is in the same folder,,still it's not working,,dont know why??                               didnt get any solution and reason ??

Comment: yup,,got the mistake,it's a quite silly mistake,,,,getting embarrased to share it...........i renamed the shortcut file as 1.lnk and then  passing the path as(C:\\...1.lnk ) instead of (C:\\....1.lnk.lnk ),,,,

Answer (score 0):

You path is wrong - '\' is a special character, to get exact this, you should double it - `"C:\\Documents and Settings\\kse8.KSE\\Desktop\\lnk file\\1.lnk"`

Comment: The string literal did escape the backslashes. It just didn't show up due to formatting.